# How Can I make my browser show files (images) that a server is sending me with download prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

The only solution I've found it to grab the link with `getElementsByClassName` then inject it into an html snippet on the page, but it looks so fake, and is also unnecessary (I don't want all the links)
I want to right click the link (one at a time) and show it to the next tab. If I right click the link the server sends me a download prompt. How can I evade this?

Comment: Don't add download headers from server side or tweak your browser settings to always open file in new tab instead of downloading.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `HTML snippet` ?

Comment: @Georges Duperon I append an img element to document and set its atribute src to the link I have grabbed. It is shown this way. I must do it for all of them though...

Comment: @MookKoom I edited my answer to indicate that you can use the `data:…` url as the URL of your new tab. If the main page can download the images itself (using `XMLHttpRequest`, or by displaying the picture in an `<img…>` tag, painting that `img` on a `<canvas>`, and extracting a PNG from the canvas), then you can automatically open many tabs, or write a series of links to `data:` URLs.

You could also have a link to a tiny web page with just the `img` tag that you currently use: `<a href="data:text/html,<img src=%22your_url%22>">link text</a>`.

Welcome to StackOverflow by the way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser decides to download a file or display it based on its MIME type.

If the server is under your control, you should make sure you supply the correct `Content-Type` HTTP header (e.g. you have to call a library function in PHP, and there should be a similar way to do that in other languages).

Otherwise, for a purely client-side solution in JavaScript, you can fetch the file with an XMLHttpRequest (most JavaScript toolkits have wrappers around it). Then, you can convert it to base 64, prefix the result `data:image/png;base64,`, and use it as the `src` attribute of an `img` element (thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/21508186/324969).

Note that for security aspects, grabbing arbitrary files and stuffing them in a `data:` URL might not be safe. I don't know if any cross-site scripting or CORS attacks could be built upon this. You'll have to ask a separate question to know if the client-side solution is unsafe. For the server-side, be careful not to set the wrong content-type for user-uploaded data, or for endpoints of your service (e.g. letting the client-side send you in the request the `Content-Type` that it would like, as tempting as it looks, is a big no-no).

To open the image in a new tab, you can use `window.open` as usual, but download the image beforehand (using `XMLHttpRequest`) and put the `data:image/png;base64,…` as the URL of the new tab.

Since you can already see the images by placing their URL in an `img` tag, you can paint that img on a , extract a PNG from the canvas, craft a `data:image/png;base64,…` URL from that, and then either automatically open many tabs with these URLS, or write in your page a series of links to `data:` URLs.

You could also have a link to a tiny web page with just the img tag that you currently use: `<a href="data:text/html,<img src=%22your_url%22>">link text</a>`.