# Is it possbile to get data of the remote image in Angularjs or pure JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, remote-access

Is it possbile to get data of the remote image which is on the remote server in pure Angular? Without using PHP Curl or similar things.

Comment: In English? I really don't understand your question.

Comment: @Michael, I'm wondering if it is possible to get base64 data from the remote image? Somehow in pure Angularjs or JS?

Comment: I think he wants to get the byte array of an image from a remote server purely in Angular.  The question I have is why?  Is there something in specific you want to do with the image?

Comment: You wanna load a base64 encoded image from a server? In that case the server has to return the encoded image. If you want to load a remote image and convert it to base64 see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: @MauriceReeves, I want to load remote images to my server and before save resize it via HTML5 canvas. The problem is I don't know how to get access to this image having only it link.

Comment: What I want is shown in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)

Comment: In fact, the answer is `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you'll probably need to use a method to convert the data. Firefox and Webkit both have a method to convert a binary stream into something that the canvas can use.

I think this question will get you most of the way to where you need to go:

[Converting bytes to an image for drawing on a HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041851/converting-bytes-to-an-image-for-drawing-on-a-html5-canvas)

Cheers.